# Need Another MongoDB Binary?

Tags: mongodb

I have a three-node MongoDB test replica running normally. I want to add an Ops Manager to it also residing on these three nodes. Do I need to install another set of MongoDB binary for the Ops Manager's databases in addition to the current replica?

Comment: ,Welcome to the site. What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need. Ops-manager just add there DB where all configuration information and collected data is kept.

Comment: Thanks JJussi for the info.